# powershell delete backed up file / archive bit / windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows, powershell, attributes, archive

I have put together a script to delete backed up files, but believe I am have the archive bit attribute confused.

```
$path = "D:\logs\"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse
$attribute = [io.fileattributes]::archive   #archive bit
$date = get-date -format d     # strip time out of date, date needed for Filename
$date = $date.replace('/','.') # strip out forward slashes and replac with . in date
$filename = "\ArchiveLog"+$date+".txt" # Filename for log file.
$location = $path+$filename 
cd D:\logs 

Foreach($file in $files)
{
 If((Get-ItemProperty -Path $file.fullname).attributes -band $attribute)
  { 
    add-content -path "$path" "$file.DirectoryName has been deleted"
    Remove-Item $file -force
  }
}
```

however when I test this, this script deletes brand new files that have just been created, as the files that are newly created have the "A" attribute or archive bit.

When I have looked at other sample scripts they usually have the line, that ensures the files archive bit is set:

```
attribute = [io.fileattributes]::archive   #archive bit
If((Get-ItemProperty -Path $file.fullname).attributes -band $attribute)
{ 
log file name    
Remove file
}
```

So ... I was wondering if this is something new to windows 2008 r2 where the archive bit "A" is set automatically upon creation, or if perhaps the other scripts I have found are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. Here's an example where I return only TXT files with the ARCHIVE attribute set:

PS C:> dir c:\work*.txt | where {$_.attributes -match "Archive"} | select name
,attributes

You can add additional filtering as needed if you only want files newer or older than a certain date.

Comment: Jeffery, yes thank you, that is much cleaner. But also... if the "Archive" attribute is set, does that mean the file is backed up, or needs to be backed up. Still searching for this, I thought that I would be able to find this information quickly, but I am having difficulty finding this on Microsofts web site.

Comment: @user1178826 the state of archive attribute  indicates whether or not the file has been backed up. When a file is created or modified the archive bit is set and when the file has been backed up the archive bit is cleared.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up, I just tested with some files and was able to verify this (sorry should have done that from the beginning) thanks again for the assistance.